# Several group totals of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to display an array (which is already has been sorted) and want to show all rows of the array including some group totals (in this case the totals of one order and the totals per month. Here is the code which I have so far. When I "strip" the code and only do the totals on either order or month is works like a charm, together I don't see the solution...

Here's the code I have so far:

```
//Put test data in an array [0] = Order, [1] = Month, [2] = Pieces
$data = array(
array("1614-0082","JAN",10),
array("1614-0082","JAN",12),
array("1614-0082","JAN",20),
array("1614-0086","JAN",81),
array("1614-0064","FEB",10),
array("1614-0064","FEB",11),
array("1614-0101","MRT",19),
array("1614-0004","OCT",13),
array("1614-0004","OCT",12),
array("1614-0023","OCT",13),
array("1614-0025","DEC",15),
array("1614-0028","DEC",15),
);

$TotalPcsO = 0; //Total per order
$TotalPcsM = 0; //Total per month
$TotalPcsG = 0; //Grand total
$j = 0;
$i = 0;
$PrevOrder = $data[0][0];
$PrevMonth = $data[0][1];
for($k = 0; $k <= sizeof($data); $k++) {
  while ($PrevMonth === $data[$i][1]) {
    while ($PrevOrder === $data[$j][0]) {
      echo $data[$j][0].' '.$data[$j][1].' '.$data[$j][2];
      echo "<br>";
      $TotalPcsO += $data[$j][2];
      $PrevOrder = $data[$j][0];
      $j++;
    }
    $i = $j;
    //Order Totals 
    echo 'Total of order '.$PrevOrder.': '.$TotalPcsO;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    $TotalPcsM += $TotalPcsO;
    $TotalPcsO = 0;
    $PrevOrder = $data[$i][0];
    $i++;
  }
  $k = $i;
  echo 'Total of month '.$PrevMonth.': '.$TotalPcsM;
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<br>";
  $TotalPcsG += $TotalPcsM;
  $TotalPcsM = 0;
  $PrevMonth = $data[$k][1];
}
//Grand Totals
  echo 'Grand total '.$TotalPcsG;
```

Comment: are you sure you have to increment $i at the end of the external while loop? You already assigned it the value of incremented $j... aren't you skipping a line here? Same remark for $k and ĵ...

Comment: In fact, why not one single iteration through the whole $data array (the for() one). For each line, If still same command as previous line, add pieces to commandPieces, if not, echo commandPieces, set it to 0 and change prevOrder; same thing for months, in the same for() loop. Just pass once through the whole array, no need for the 2 while loops i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... it's not the way I would have done it, but based on your code, at least it should work...

```
    $TotalPcsO = 0; //Total per order
    $TotalPcsM = 0; //Total per month
    $TotalPcsG = 0; //Grand total
    $PrevOrder = $data[0][0];
    $PrevMonth = $data[0][1];
    foreach($data as $row) {
        $TotalPcsG+=$row[2];
        if($row[0]==$PrevOrder) $TotalPcsO += $row[2];
        else {
            echo "Total of order $PrevOrder: $TotalPcsO<br /><br />";
            $PrevOrder=$row[0];
            $TotalPcsO=$row[2];
        }
        if($row[1]==$PrevMonth) $TotalPcsM += $row[2];
        else {
            echo "Total of month $PrevOrder: $TotalPcsM<br /><br />";
            $PrevMonth=$row[1];
            $TotalPcsM=$row[2];
        }
        echo $row[0].' '.$row[1].' '.$row[2].'<br />';
    }
    echo "Total of order $PrevOrder: $TotalPcsO<br /><br />";
    echo "Total of month $PrevOrder: $TotalPcsM<br /><br />";
    echo "Grand total: $TotalPcsG";
```

Comment: Many thanks, I have a lot to learn in programming... that's for sure! This solution is perfect! Using if's iso loops, never to old to learn!